# Create edges list with weights from flat list using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server I have an input list (like below), where the **groups** are the edges of future graph:

```
group 1, user 1
group 1, user 2
group 1, user 3
group 2, user 1
group 2, user 3
group 3, user 1
group 4, user 4
```

How to create a list of edges, where the weights will be the number of common participants between groups, using SQL tools?

```
group 1, group 2, 2
group 1, group 3, 1
group 2, group 3, 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use a self join and aggregation:

```
select g1.groupid, g2.groupid, count(*)
from graph g1 join
     graph g2
     on g1.userid = t2.userid and g1.groupid < g2.groupid
group by g1.groupid, g2.groupid;
```